# Print Dynamic content on cetificate

Tags: php, laravel

I want to print certificate for students dynamically by fetching their data and inputt them on to the certificate template.

I have the cetificate template in a image format. I have no problem with fetching the data from the database.
.

The problem is how to input the details on certificate dynamically for printing.

I'm using laravel framework.
Thanks

Comment: Post some code you have written so far!

Comment: Ok but I want to know if its possible. Or do I have design the certificate in html instead of having the jpeg format?